# Can I use weather stripping inside a shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower

We are installing a shower base and there is a little gap between the drywall and the shower base. I did some research and the TrimLux from Sealux is perfect for our problem. The only problem is that I can't get it. But I saw a similar profile on a weather stripping. Is it possible to use weather stripping to cover the gap?[image][image]

Comment: How big is the gap?  Photos?

Comment: The gap is about 1/8" wide. I would love to send photos but we're putting in tile right now. I'll show photos as soon as we're done tiling.

Comment: I added the picture above. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Caulking is the standard method for shower/baths. 100% silicone mildew resistant caulking.

I do not think the weather striping is going to eliminate water from wicking up from the bottom.

Is there going to be something installed over the the drywall?

Comment: Yes, there will be tile over the weather stripping. Although, i put a bead of silicone i underneath the weather stripping, in between the gap of the base and the wall. Im just using the weather stripping for added protection and as a means for the tile to drop on to

Comment: Usually the product  that you are  mounting the tile to, cement board or denshield or whatever it may be will be, is sitting out further than the shower base or tub so that when you put the tile on the tile comes down over the tub lip or shower base lip.  IE: the base runs up behind the tile. It seams in your case you are going to but the tile up to the base, if so the the weather strip may get in the way or be visible and not look good. ??

Comment: Yeah, thats what it should be. But my dad did it the way it is now. Its looking okay now though. Im just concerned about the weather stripping degrading because it'll be in the shower.